# Date.UTC() returns last day of previous month while getUTCFullYear(), getUTCMonth() returns correctly first day of correct month

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I'm getting a strange result:

```
   var date = new Date();
   var year  = date.getMonth() < 11 ? date.getFullYear() : date.getFullYear() + 1;
   var month = date.getMonth() < 11 ? date.getMonth() + 1 : 0;

   console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(year, month)));

   var utcYear = date.getUTCMonth() < 11 ? date.getUTCFullYear() : date.getUTCFullYear() + 1;
   var utcMonth = date.getUTCMonth() < 11 ? date.getUTCMonth() + 1 : 0;

   console.log(new Date(utcYear, utcMonth));
```

With the particular date I'm using (any date will do), Date.UTC gives me:

Sun May 31 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

The getUTC... aproach gives me:

Mon Jun 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

Am I mis-using Date.UTC or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are misusing `Date.UTC` because you pass local values to it (and your are misusing `new Date` because you pass utc values to it). What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It's an angular service to return a date object in UTC time.  This code is to get the first day of the next month (something that reoccurs monthly and can't start until next month).

Comment: JS `Date` objects do not have a timezone attached, they are just absolute timestamps. For display, you either use UTC or local `get…` and `to…String` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a Date using UTC time, but then you are displaying it in local time, that's why it's a few hours behind. Use [Date.prototype.toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) to see the UTC time

```js
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getMonth() < 11 ? date.getFullYear() : date.getFullYear() + 1;
  var month = date.getMonth() < 11 ? date.getMonth() + 1 : 0;

  // It's a UTC date, display it as UTC, not local time
  console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(year, month)).toUTCString());

  var utcYear = date.getUTCMonth() < 11 ? date.getUTCFullYear() : date.getUTCFullYear() + 1;
  var utcMonth = date.getUTCMonth() < 11 ? date.getUTCMonth() + 1 : 0;

  // Created using local time, you can just use the normal toString()
  console.log(new Date(utcYear, utcMonth));
```

Comment: It's not only a display issue. He is constructing dates using UTC but passing local time value (and in reverse), which is just wrong.

Comment: @Bergi I do realize that, I didn't try to explain how to properly work use UTC or local times. There are too many variables for me to try to talk about it without knowing exactly what the OP is trying to do. I just solved the problem I saw :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  So it looks like it's just the display string.

Comment: To clarify I don't need to display it just returning a date object in UTC.  the actual date being used is not a local one.  was trying to figure out the discrepancy.  Thanks again guys.

Comment: @Chris: Again, there are not "date objects in UTC". The code in this answer still generates `Date` objects that are off.

Comment: @Chris The constructor for Date that takes the number of ms since epoch (which is what `Date.UTC` returns) is always UTC. Every date is stored in UTC, when it gets displayed, it gets displayed as local time, unless you specify toUTCString, in which case it gets displayed as UTC time

Comment: @Chris When you call `new Date(utcYear, utcMonth))`, you're creating a date at 12:00 for local time, but when you create a date using `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month)` you're creating a date at 12:00 for UTC time

Comment: @Bergi: Yes I get what you are saying.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> This code is to get the first day of the next month (something that reoccurs monthly and can't start until next month).

Then you're looking for

```
var today = new Date(); // now

var utcYear = today.getUTCMonth() < 11 ? today.getUTCFullYear() : today.getUTCFullYear() + 1;
var utcMonth = today.getUTCMonth() < 11 ? today.getUTCMonth() + 1 : 0;

var date = new Date(Date.UTC(utcYear, utcMonth)); // next UTC month
console.log(date.toString()); // Mon Jun 01 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 
// or, in your timezone:         Sun May 31 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (same moment)
console.log(date.toUTCString()); // Mon, 01 Jun 2015 00:00:00 GMT
```

Btw, the `Date` methods does take too large values into accout (and carry-over them automatically), so you just would need to do

```
var today = new Date(); // now
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(today.getUTCFullYear(), today.getUTCMonth()+1)); // next UTC month
```